# How to send a message in event handler in akka.net?

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have an actor that has a custom timer that fires events in non real-time intervals. (This is why I cannot use scheduler) 
In event handler I want to send a message to self or another actor. I am receiving an NotSupportedException.

I have a custom time source similliar to the NodaTime FakeClock class.

```
public class NodaTimeControllableClock
{
    public void AddInterval(Duration interval);
    public Instant Now { get; protected set; }
    public event EventHandler<TimeChangedEventArgs<Duration>> TimeChanged;
}
```

It is used in timer class to trigger events every specified amount of time.

```
public class NodaTimer
{
    Duration Interval { get; set; }
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    bool IsRunning { get; private set; }
    event EventHandler<TimerTickedEventArgs> TimerTicked;
}
```

Now, I create a timer instance for some of my actors and store it inside them.

```
protected override void PreStart()
{
    base.PreStart();
    timer.Interval = Duration.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.TimerTicked += Timer_TimerTicked; 
    timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_TimerTicked(object sender, TimerTickedEventArgs e)
{
    Self.Tell(new SomeMessage());
    //Here I want to send the message to the parent or 
    //if it's impossible to do so I could queue some message
    //to the Self messagebox.
}
```

What is the pattern to work with sending messages on events? Is there any?

Comment: Could you provide some simple snippet?

Comment: Done. Does this provide enough details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the source of your issues is `Self` member call made inside `Timer_TimerTicked`. Reason for this is that `Self` just like `Context` is a computed property, that is available only within currently executing actor's thread. If you call it from the outside (another thread like in the case of timer callbacks), it may be not initialized.

Weak solution is just to store reference to `Self` in some other field, and use that field to send message instead.

Better solution in your case is to use built-in Akka.NET Scheduler, which offers ability to perform actions or make calls in specified time intervals:

```
class MyActor : ReceiveActor
{
    private readonly ICancelable cancelTimer;

    public MyActor()
    {
        var interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        cancelTimer = Context.System.Scheduler
            .ScheduleTellRepeatedlyCancelable(interval, interval, Self, new SomeMessage(), ActorRefs.NoSender);
    }

    protected override void PostStop()
    {
        cancelTimer.Cancel();
        base.PostStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love to use Scheduler, but it uses real-time clock, right? Can it even be replaced with my own implementation?

Comment: For testing purposes (Akka.TestKit) there's an implementation which implements virtual time: you can basically call `Scheduler.Advance` to move forward by specified amout of time.

Comment: I'm writing a simulator where the time control is a part of the application.